# Transaction rollback working yet an error is still getting generated

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to run this T-SQL in SQL Server Management Studio:

```
BEGIN TRAN;

DELETE FROM [TestDB].[dbo].[TestTable];

IF @@ROWCOUNT > 1
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK COMMIT;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    COMMIT TRAN;
END
```

The `TestTable` has more than 1 row so the `ROLLBACK COMMIT;` line is getting executed. I also note that the table doesn't get cleared of its records which indicates that the rollback worked. However, I am still getting the below error on the line where the rollback occurs.

> (13 rows affected)
> Msg 3902, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
> The COMMIT TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION.

What could be the cause for the error even though everything seems to be functioning as expected?

Comment: The syntax is being abbreviated.  I always wrote `BEGIN TRAN`, `ROLLBACK TRAN`, `COMMIT TRAN`.  There is no such thing as `ROLLBACK COMMIT`.

Comment: Seems inefficient to delete the whole table only to roll it back. Maybe do `DELETE TOP (2) dbo.TestTable;` then you've never deleted more than two rows. An even better solution might be to select the top two rows using `UPDLOCK` so you don't even do any modifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem line contains 2 separate statements:

> ```
> ROLLBACK COMMIT;
> ```

It is functionally identical to

```
ROLLBACK;
COMMIT;
```

You get the error because the transaction was rolled back by the first statement so there is no open transaction to commit by the second statement.

Remove the `COMMIT` to rollback the transaction and avoid the error.